# Java Check if HttpResponse is Still Alive

Tags: java, ajax, httpresponse

Is there a way from a java servlet to check if the httpresponse is still "alive?" For instance, in my situation I send an ajax request from the browser over to a servlet. In this case its a polling request so it may poll for up to 5 minutes, when the servlet is ready to respond with data i'd like to check if the user has closed the browser window, or moved to another page etc. In other words, check to see if sending the data to the response will actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this problem can be solved by sending a dummy payload before the actual message.

If the socket was severed, an `IOException` or  a `SocketException` or something similar is thrown (depending on the library). Technically, browsers are supposed to sever a connection whenever you navigate away from a page or close the browser (or anything similar), but I've found out that the implementation details can vary. Older versions of FF, for example, appropriately close a connection when navigating away from a page, but newer versions (especially when using AJAX) tend to leave connections open.

That's the main reason you may use a dummy packet before the actual message. Another important consideration is the timeout. I've done polling before and you either need to implement some sort of heartbeat to keep a connection alive or increase the server timeout (although keep in mind that some browsers may have timeouts as well - timeouts that you have no control over).

Instead of polling or pushing over AJAX, I strongly suggest trying to support (at least in part) a Websocket solution.

Comment: A timeout is the main reason I need to check for the open connection. Basically I have a list of active users and if the poll times out it automatically sends a null response. If the connection is still active, it will receive that null value and respond back and I know to keep the active user alive. I guess I could remove the user each time and let a successful response reactive, but it seemed a little hacky. In this situation, websockets seemed overkill, long polling is still a quite viable solution.

Comment: So is returning the value as I described and removing the active user and allowing a response to reset that user essentially the same thing as sending a dummy packet?

Comment: Yeah, it's virtually the same thing, a heartbeat is just a bit more robust. Websockets may seem overkill, but they handle socket severing very graciously (via `onClose()` handlers) that are called by all browsers.

Comment: Can you describe implementing a heartbeat a little better? I'm sorry, i'm not really sure what that means?

Comment: Server-side, you have a timer that runs (say every 10 seconds), and sends a message to connected clients (something like `ping`). If the client navigates off the webpage and the browser fails to close the connection (as it should), the heartbeat will catch that and you can rest assured that you won't have any dangling clients (which is usually my main issue as I don't want to waste resources on clients that have disconnected).

Answer (score 0):

Java Servlet Response doesn't have any such method as it is based on request and response behavior. If you wish to check the status, then probably you need to work at lower level e.g. [**TCP/IP Sockets**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), which has several status check methods as below:

```
boolean isBound()
Returns the binding state of the socket.

boolean isClosed()
Returns the closed state of the socket.

boolean isConnected()
Returns the connection state of the socket.

boolean isInputShutdown()
Returns whether the read-half of the socket connection is closed.

boolean isOutputShutdown()
Returns whether the write-half of the socket connection is closed.
```

Comment: Wouldn't creating a socket listen to only the ip and port? Therefore, checking if its still open would return true if anyone was on the site? Or would this somehow be user specific?